# the usage of offset for storing (stw) in powerpc assembly

Tags: offset, disassembly, powerpc

```
long long int i=57745158985; #the C code 

0000000000100004:   li r7,13
0000000000100008:   lis r8,29153
000000000010000c:   ori r8,r8,0x3349
0000000000100010:   stw r7,24(rsp)
0000000000100014:   stw r8,28(rsp)
0000000000100018:   lfd fp0,24(rsp)
000000000010001c:   stfd fp0,8(rsp)
```

Can anyone explain the part of after the `ori` instruction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is on a 32-bit big endian machine. I will assume `i` is a local variable.

Starting with these instructions...

```
li r7,13 
lis r8,29153 
ori r8,r8,0x3349
```

After these instructions:

- `r7 contains 13`
- `r8 contains ((29153 << 16) | 0x3349)`

The required value for i is `57745158985`, which is equal to

```
(13<<32) |  ((29153 << 16) | 0x3349)
```

Clearly this value is too big to fit in a single 32-bit register.

The next instructions are where the 64-bit local variable `i` is "created" on the stack.

```
stw r7,24(rsp) 
stw r8,28(rsp)
```

`rsp` is the stack pointer for the function.
Here `i` is being initialized to it's initial value of `57745158985`.

- `stw r7,24(rsp)` stores the four bytes of `r7` starting at an offset of `24` bytes into the stack.
- `stw r8,28(rsp)` stores the four bytes `r8` starting at an offset of `28` bytes into the stack.

So `i` is the 8 bytes starting from an offset of `24` on the stack.

As this is a big-endian architecture the most significant bytes are placed first in memory.
Placing the value of `r7` at lower address performs acts like the `(13<<32)` when considering the 8 bytes as one `long long int`.

These next instructions load the value of `i` into a floating point register and save it at a different location on the stack.

```
lfd fp0,24(rsp) 
stfd fp0,8(rsp)
```

Comment: actually I figured out the logic in the code. But I was debuing on the Code Warrior (32bit) and building the code on the t1024RDB(64bit). All the registers worked normally. But the rsp(R1) resister never changed. I couldnt see the offset situation and initiliazing. Do u have some info about sir?

Comment: The memory addressed by the stw instruction is calculated by adding the literal (e.g. 24) to the value held in the register (e.g. r1). The value in r1 is not changed. This information is available in the Instruction Set Architecture.

Answer (score 1):

These 3 are loading up two 32 bit literal values into GPRs r7 and r8

```
0000000000100004: li r7,13 
0000000000100008: lis r8,29153
000000000010000c: ori r8,r8,0x3349
```

These two are storing the two 32 bit values out consecutive 32 bit memory locations pointed to by rsp (which is the stack pointer == r1) + 24

```
0000000000100010: stw r7,24(rsp)
0000000000100014: stw r8,28(rsp)
```

This is a 64 bit load from the same location (ie rsp + 24) into floating point register 0 (ie fp0). (you can't move GPRs to FPR directly on this processor, so you go via memory)

```
0000000000100018: lfd fp0,24(rsp)
```

This is storing the same 64 bit FPR0 out to a different offset from the stack point.

```
000000000010001c: stfd fp0,8(rsp)
```